# Apache2 send request to a path and all its subpaths to another source

Tags: apache, tomcat7

I have a server running Apache 2.2, where i have an instance of WordPress installed.

I also have a tomcat7 server running with a webapp on port 8080.

I wish to send everyrequest to the tomcat server but the blog ones like: /blog, /blog/, /blog/2017/02/10/blog-title-here/, etc...

i currently managed to have /blog going to the right place, but not the individual posts, they always go to the tomcat7 and i don't know why.

Here's my configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http"

    AddDefaultCharset utf-8

    ServerAdmin contact@example.com
    ServerName server.example.com

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>

    Alias "/blog" "/var/www/www.example.com"
    <Directory /var/www/www.example.com>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass "/blog" "!"
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8080/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:8080/"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName server.example.com

    <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>

    Alias "/blog" "/var/www/www.example.com"
    <Directory /var/www/www.example.com>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass "/blog" "!"
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8080/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:8080/"

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/wildcard.example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/wildcard.example.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/rapidssl_intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

The main parts being:

```
    Alias "/blog" "/var/www/www.example.com"
    (...)
    ProxyPass "/blog" "!"
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8080/"
```

Where i'm aliasing everything starting with /blog and sending it to where the wordpress is and not proxying it. And proxying everything from / to tomcat.

The only thing i can't work out why it's not working is requests to /blog/ not working.

I've tried ProxyPassMatch, and AliasMatch, can't do it.
Any help appreciated.